# How do I check if a terminal is available through my gnuplot script?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to set terminal to pngcairo instead of png whenever the pngcairo terminal is available,
and I don't want to manually check for its availability and update my script everytime.

When pngcairo terminal is not available, I get the following error in my script:

```
set terminal pngcairo
             ^
"./script.gnuplot", line 7: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
```

How do I test for pngcairo's availability in my gnuplot script so that I can set terminal to png in its absence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All available terminals are available through the variable `GPVAL_TERMINALS`, see `show variables all`. With the `strstrt` function you can check if `pngcairo` is available:

```
if (strstrt(GPVAL_TERMINALS, 'pngcairo') > 0) {
    set terminal pngcairo
} else {
    set terminal png
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it, can you elaborate on this strstrt

Comment: `strstrt("string","key")` searches for the character string "key" in "string"                                                         
 and returns the index to the first character of "key". If "key" is not found,                                                         
 returns 0. Similar to C library function strstr except that it returns an                                                             
 index rather than a string pointer. strstrt("hayneedlestack","needle") = 4.